# how to convert DateTime into Unix TimeStamp in F#?

Tags: datetime, f#, unix-timestamp

is there a function / library / easy snippet doing that ?

I've found answers for Python for example, but not F# thanks

I've found the other way round here
http://tryfs.net/snippets/snippet-r6

```
open System

let toDateTime (timestamp:int) = 
    let start = DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,DateTimeKind.Utc) 
    start.AddSeconds(float timestamp).ToLocalTime()
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimeseconds.aspx

Comment: The methods to convert from and to UnixTime (in the above link) were added in .NET 4.6.x. So please target the most recent version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be careful because `timestamp` might be something else than `int`. However in .NET 4.6.x you should be able to use the functions referred to in the comments.

[image: .NET 4.6.2]

Here's an example:

```
open System
let unix = DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now).ToUnixTimeSeconds() //val unix : int64 = 1488254491L
let dt =  DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(unix)  //val dt : DateTimeOffset = 2017/02/28 4:01:31 +00:00
dt.LocalDateTime //val it : DateTime = 2017/02/28 13:01:31
```

As `ToUnixTimeSeconds` and `FromUnixTimeSeconds` operates on `DateTimeOffset`, either work with that or convert back/forth to `DateTime` if necessary.

By the way I find it that in the .fsx file the intellisense is a bit flaky for these methods (but works). In .fs files it's OK.

Comment: What if I need to use an earlier version (#NET 4.5) ?

Comment: @FaguiCurtain I don't understand your question, you show yourself a snippet on how to calculate it in your question, there are quite  a few similar code snippets on SO as well. Basically you add back the time since the epoch.